# Plot values on plot.style line

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How I can plot with price at end of line on the chart.

```
plot(Plot_eNtrylines ? Target:na, title="Target ATR", style = plot.style_line, color = color.rgb(139, 69, 19,2),display=display.all)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'label' :

```
if Plot_eNtrylines
    label.new(bar_index, Target, "Target ATR", text = str.tostring(Target))
```

Comment: @rt1050 did you try my answer ?

Comment: Yes I got idea to figure out. I have used last.bar_index and text needs only one time.